# I need to pull distinct date timestamps from SQL. They are currently in date and time format and I need only the distinct dates

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I split the value so that I only receive the date in my results and exclude the time using my `SELECT DISTINCT` statement?

Here is an example:
`16-JUN-14 11.06.45.000000000`
I only want:
`16-JUN-14`

I tried the split and the date function but unfortunately couldn't get either to work.

Comment: Please clarify what DB you use: MS SQL Server or MySQL. They are different

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (The answer will not be the same for both.)

Comment: Guess what? MySQL is a totally different product to SQL Server - do yourself a favour and correct your tags so the right experts look at your post.

Comment: I've gone ahead and removed the conflicting tags. You'll need to [edit] the question to (re)add the relevant (R)DBMS for what your *actually* asking about.

Comment: Please show us your `SELECT DISTINCT` statement with your attempt. Also have you checked out `CONVERT`? With the correct style it might do what you want, or close at least. Of course presentation matters should be dealt with in the presentation layer not SQL.

Comment: ```TRUNC(date)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value you posted looks like a timestamp. In that case, truncate it to "remove" time part (actually, you'd set it to midnight):

```
SQL> select systimestamp, trunc(systimestamp) from dual;

SYSTIMESTAMP
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TRUNC(SYS
---------
21-MAR-23 08.04.43.606000 PM +01:00
21-mar-23


SQL>
```

It means that you'd

```
select distinct trunc(your_timestamp_column) from your_table
```

---

(`trunc` does the same on `date` datatype.)